# For Biking do Sneakers offer any advantage over Sandals?

Tags: evaluation

I live in a tropical country. We have only two seasons. A rainy season that lasts for 4 months and a summer lasting the remaining 8 months.

The maximum and minimum temperatures are 36 and 20 degrees Celsius respectively.

I ride my hybrid cycle almost every day for exercise.

The sneakers get wet during the rainy season and the feet get too warm during summer.

Therefore, I find it comfortable and convenient to wear waterproof sports sandals with back straps when riding my bike.

My question is do sneakers (sports shoes) offer any special advantages when biking over sandals?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Wear socks when you wear sandals. Because sandal lining are not makde from soft fabric, and sweat will make the slipper slipped.

Comment: Thank you mootmoot; I appreciate your suggestion that I wear socks. Yes, cotton socks will absorb the sweat and protect the feet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The late Sheldon Brown, whose advice is treasured on this web site, wore sandals in all seasons, including winter in New England (snow and ice).  He wore sandals that had SPD cleats on the bottom.  Details are on [this page](http://sheldonbrown.com/shoe-pedal.html) from his web site.

I would say that as long as the sandals don't slip on the pedals more than the sneakers do, then there are no advantages to the sneakers.

Answer (score 3):

1 advantage is in an accident it's harder to rip a toenail off.

Answer (score 1):

For commuting in warm wet conditions I found sports sandals ideal before (switching to clipless).  A couple of things are worth noting though:

- If you push down hard on the pedal, some soles curl down towards the pedal.  Do this on a tight bend or with a low bottom bracket and the sole can brush 
  the ground.  It's not really dangerous, but rather disconcerting.
- Stones flicked up by the front wheel really sting if they hit your toes.
- Some sandals have slippy soles; others don't fasten to your feet well enough to not slide around.

I went for somehting like [this random ebay hit](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/plus-size-beach-shoes-casual-shoes-mens-sport-sandal-Flat-buckle-strap-new-/311622604435?var=&hash=item488e279693:m:m2wKSh3lOfEtbuVAZD6pYGQ) which didn't slide around on my foot even when wet, and was as good as trainers for gripping the pedals.

Comment: Shimano make sandals that can be used with their SPD mountain pedals. (http://www.wiggle.com/shimano-sd66-spd-sandals/)

Comment: @Carel that's good to know, though my shoes have mesh panels on the uppers.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. 

The sandals I propose to buy will have two or three straps on the uppers and I think this will prevent the sole from curling downwards.

Stones pose no problem because I ride on tarred roads.

The back strap fastened with a Velcro fastener will keep the feet in place inside the sandal without letting them slide on the insole.

Comment: @Chris, I'm buying this. How do you like it? 

http://www.amazon.in/FUEL-MEN-KEEN-YELLOW-SANDAL/dp/B01F6ZZX1Y/ref=pd_sim_sbs_309_2?ie=UTF8&dpID=4116-5oktVL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_&refRID=04Z7EPRRP3RE8GFNFNFD

Comment: @Ali I have sandals that are very similar to those and I really like them for cycling. Soft soles means that they grip well on the pedals and the toes have some protection.  Very light weight and comfortable. They dry out reasonably fast if they get wet.

Comment: @Kibbee. That's very comforting to know.